# React/TS Show YYYY/MM/DD on ONE method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I get YYYY/MM/DD data on ONE method?
I already tried this,

```
date = created_at // from API
const sendDate = `${String((date.getMonth() + 1)).padStart(2, '0')}${String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')}${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}
```

but it looks messy.
Is there any method to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
import moment from "moment";

const sendDate = moment(created_at).format('YYYY/MM/DD');    
console.log(sendDate);
```

Comment: Thanks! but I've heard 'moment' is not appropriate because of the mutability. Is that okay?

Comment: @kotaroTakenaka moment is the best library for it, everyone is using it. You can use it

Comment: check out https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs if youre worried about mutability

Comment: @DaveAnkin I just found this project already imported moment haha, but thanks! I'll use them next time :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way could be using [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) and use `.format` method

```
import moment from "moment";

export default function App () {

  console.log(moment(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD'));

  return (..)
}
```